# crystal reports footer group sum

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I want to sum the total amount of a field(it has to lines in sql so  value should be 44+250=294) which belongs to a group but it peaks only the first line(44).

For example below is the formula that i have created.

```
if Sum({STOCK.QTYSTU_0},{@pickGrp3}) -Sum ({STOALL.QTYSTUACT_0}, {@pickGrp3}) = 0 then "EMPTY" else " "
```

Can you please advise?

Comment: Do your field values appear normally in detail section? Is your summary displayed in footer? And can you be more clear about the formula and {STOCK.QTYSTU_0},{STOALL.QTYSTUACT_0} and {@pickGrp3}?

Comment: {STOCK.QTYSTU_0} this field in SQL has two lines with values 44 and 250. So the field picks only the first line(44) and messes up the formula where I would like it to do 44 + 250 =294. Hence I would like to place the formula inside a group.

Comment: The {STOCK.QTYSTU_0} its not {STOCK.QTYSTU_0}  and {@pickGrp3}?  the group that we have in our crystal. Summary is displayed in Group Footer.

Comment: Is your formula placed in group footer too?

Comment: I agree with @jambonick, the formula needs to be placed under the group footer, this should resolve your issue.

Comment: Yes it is. GroupFooter3.